# Por qué no se muestra el resultado en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

El problema es que quiero que se le asigne a una variable en javascript el atributo href cada vez que se genera el evento click, pero luego quiero que la pase a php para poder hacer un query que registre en la base de datos, tengo el siguiente código, cuando hago esto localmente me funciona pero cuando lo hago en un servidor, no funciona, por qué será?

```
<?php
function salir(){
        $xx = '<script> document.write(x); </script>';
        echo $xx;
    }
?>

<html>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('body a').click(function(){
            var x = $(this).attr('href');
            document.write('<?php salir(); ?>')
          })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Codigo original.

lo que quiero es que de la variable $xx de php obtenga el valor de la variable que tiene javascript para que al momento de que ya pueda estar en php pueda manejarla a mi antojo y poder realizar querys con ese valor, por ejemplo: insert into tabla values (7,$xx,'algo');

Comment: Si dice que en local le funciona, pero en el servidor no, lo más probable es que sea un problema de rutas. Qué sale en la consola?. Por cierto, ese es todo el código?.

Comment: Ya le coloque toda la direccion que me da mi cpanel pero aún así no aparece, para comprobarlo hice que me diera un error un archivo que está en el mismo directorio de ese, entonces el directorio no está mal.

Comment: El res.php está en la raíz de su proyecto?. Trate de subir una imagen de la estructura de sus carpetas y añada más código html, ya que no veo el "a" que se le dará click, etc.

Comment: Ya modifique el codigo que estaba al codigo original que tengo, espero pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

Si te funciona bien localmente pero mal en el servidor, no creo que sea problema del código. Supongo que es un tema de configuración del servidor de producción. En tu lugar lo que haría es revisar la configuración local y compararla con el servidor. 
Sería importante conocer detalles como en que servidor estás desarrollando y cual es el de producción, si lo has instalado o es un Hosting contratado y cosas como esas.

Yo suelo usar siempre Apache Server pero si contrato un servicio que tiene otro software es probable que tenga problemas, por ejemplo. No sé, pueden ser muchas cosas.

No queda otra que ir a las más simples y probables e ir descartando.

Espero lo soluciones. Saludos